# Mac export APNS Certificate with/without Private Key difference

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2003

I have a question regarding the **difference** between exporting **APNS Certificate with private key and without private key**.

I am maintaining an existing iPhone app with push notification feature. It is already working very well. No problem on that.

But this was my situation the other day:

The **apns certificate** to receive push is **about to expire** and the client wants me to **create a new** apns certificate and export it as **.p12** and give to them for them to put in server. I was not the main developer for this and have no idea on how they have exported the certificate before. I don't handle the server also. The client doesn't have an idea as well. Even the person who handles the server side. whew!

So the best option would be to **export the certificate together with the private key** (as just everyone is pointing out on every site I visited) and save it as **p12 file**. But when we put it in the server, **we cannot receive a push**. There must be something wrong. Without enough reason to do so, I tried to **export only the certificate without the private key** *(and **save it as p12** file)* and put it in the server. And boom, it works. We were **able to receive push**.

Now I ask. In most tutorials for exporting apns certificates, it always indicates to include the private key. Even [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html) said so. But in our side, it only needs to have the certificate. I really don't understand what's the reason behind this.

Can someone give me a clue so that I can properly understand how this works and the others not? A link would be helpful, opinions and knowledge very much appreciated.

By the way, the server is in **Windows Server 2003**.

Thank you all in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: I think, new certificate has problems, this is why it isn't working. When you install the certificate without private key, it doesn't work either. Apparently, only previous certificate works when no other valid certificates exist.

Comment: The new exported certificate is working now. When I exported it without the private key. That was not even my question. This was my question:

"Now I ask. In most tutorials for exporting apns certificates, it always indicates to include the private key. Even apple documentation said so. But in our side, it only needs to have the certificate. I really don't understand what's the reason behind this."

Comment: Can you please clarify? You're saying that you want to _receive_ push notifications - but the APNS certificate is there to _send_ push notifications. It has to be a p12 file (from my perspective, we're doing it that way for years).